# Ninject IntransientScope not working with DBContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, scope, ninject, dispose

Working with EntityFramework and Ninject i need to dispose the context each time a call to a repository is finished. I need that so each time, a new call to the database is made, instead of using the EF context scope.

Here is my repository for testing:

```
public class VehicleRepositoryTest : IVehicleRepository
{
    private DBEntities _context;

    public VehicleRepositoryTest(DBEntities context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    ....
    public List<TB_VEHICULO> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.TB_VEHICULO.ToList();
    }
```

And here is how i implement the ninject module. I use "IntransientScope" with the idea of disposing the context after each call:

```
Kernel.Bind<DBEntities>().ToSelf().InTransientScope();

Kernel.Bind<IVehicleRepository>().To<Test.VehicleRepositoryTest>().InTransientScope();
```

The idea is that each time a call "GetAll()" a new context is created, so each time a call to database is made.

But it is not working. If i make a call to "GetAll()", and supose i get data A; then i change in database data A to data B, make a new call to "GetAll()", i still getting data A.

**More Info:**

My application is a WinForms application, to call the instantiate the injected objects i use the composition pattern:

```
public static class CompositionRoot
{
    public static IKernel kernel { get; private set; }
    public static void WireModule(INinjectModule module)
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel(module);
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return kernel.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

and the call to the repository is like this:

```
_vehicleRepository = CompositionRoot.Resolve<IVehicleRepository>();
var test = _vehicleRepository.GetAll();
```

Comment: `if i make a call to "GetAll()", and supose i get data A; then i change in database data A to data B, make a new call to "GetAll()", i still getting data A.` are you sure this is really happening?

Comment: Yes, in fact, if i change the body of the method "GetAll()" to using(DBEntities context = new DBEntities()){return context.TB_VEHICULO.ToList();} it works perfectly... But well, in that case i'm not using Ninject, so that is why i suppose the problem is with the way Ninject disposes the context

Comment: This is really strange. Actually disposing the context is the responsibility of DI provider.

Comment: Please use `kernel.Bind(typeof(DBEntities)).To(typeof(DBEntities));`

            `kernel.Bind(typeof(IVehicleRepository)).To(typeof(VehicleRepository));` instead of your code and let me know the result. and don't use `.InTransientScope();`

Comment: same result. Thanks

Comment: Surely you are missing something? I am also using `ninject` but didn't face such problem.

Comment: To be more confirmed I have just checked it again in my project with your scenario. It always returning the update value.

Comment: I've updated my question with more info. Thank you in any case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187274/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-morgoz).

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem.

My old code:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IUnitOfWork)).To<UnitOfWork>().WithConstructorArgument("context", kernel.Get<MyContext>());
```

My new Code:

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<MyContext>();
kernel.Bind(typeof(IUnitOfWork)).To<UnitOfWork>();
```

This work to me.